# Are any of these lenses currently available or is this a case of unreproducable, unlikley to be of use to future users?

Tags: discussion

I voted to close [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173710/how-to-launch-ask-ubuntu-lens) as it appears to be unavailable for currently supported releases and therefor unlikely to be of use. It has no upvoted/accepted answers. I also stumbled across [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31712/how-do-i-install-the-ask-ubuntu-unity-lens-and-how-do-i-use-it) which appears to have been useful for a period of time but doesn't appear to be useful now. I also found [this big list question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38772/what-lenses-for-unity-are-available) and did some random spot checking and couldn't find any of these projects currently in development/available for currently supported versions. I'm wondering at what point historical value outweighs usefulness to future users or if indeed it ever does? Should we VTC all or some of these and what criteria is most logical to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My opinion is dupe [How to launch ask ubuntu lens?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173710/how-to-launch-ask-ubuntu-lens) as a dupe of [How do I install the Ask Ubuntu Unity Lens, and how do I use it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31712/how-do-i-install-the-ask-ubuntu-unity-lens-and-how-do-i-use-it) The second one is still valid as 12.04 is still supported and usually we don't close questions  because they are not relevant anymore.

The big list one should just be left alone and I don't think the others a quite duplicates of that one and again 12.04 is still supported.

Here is a meta SE post about closing old question here [How should Ask Ubuntu handle old questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217325/how-should-ask-ubuntu-handle-old-questions-and-answers)

Comment: Point taken regarding 12.04. Clearly I'm premature. So what happens come April when 12.04 falls off the supported list? I'd also like to see more discussion on this [related moderation issue](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16361/what-criteria-should-be-used-when-considering-merge-candidates)

Comment: "So what happens come April when 12.04 falls off the supported list?" That is a good question, consider adding it to your original post. I see your point better now and I do agree, we should have a way of saying "this no longer works" and that close reason would be best. Also perhaps an edit in the questions or answers indicating ones that don't work on supported releases. IDK if there is a set way to handle it. I guess, as the users of this site, this is very much the kind of thing we should be looking out for and acting upon.

Comment: I  Agree that it would be useful to have a consensus regarding no longer supported solutions that simply will not work or could even be dangerous as in th SE post you linked. I hesitate to change this question as I don't want to render your very complete answer questionable (pun intended) ;-) I think in the past there's been a call to action regarding Spring Cleanup. I'll do some digging and if I can't find anything I'll post a new one.