# What ever happend to clean up week?

Tags: discussion, cleanup

Going off Elder Geeks post [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16566/are-any-of-these-lenses-currently-available-or-is-this-a-case-of-ureproducable) where clean up was discussed, what happened to [clean up week](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2863/its-time-for-clean-up-week)?

It seems to of [only run for one week](http://cleanup.thepcspy.com/leaderboard/2/), years ago.

What happened to it and could we bring it back? The user base is bigger now and I think many would take part.

Opinions?

Comment: I like the idea of this. We could keep queues down, and if we're thinking about reviewing, we might be more likely to peruse the home page and vote/close/answer/comment new questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two big things changed for me:

- Review was invented.
- The system deals with most of this stuff by itself.

From my personal viewpoint —that I seem to push every chance I can— I really think we can stop worrying about the old crap that we used to say would clog up the internet. These days *I* think The most helpful thing you can do on the site today is answer a post, and anything that draws people away from that focus isn't in the site's best interest.

I do think there is room for a new companion project to guide people towards stuff that needs attention. If I were building that today it would be far more focussed on linking people with questions they can answer, and getting them to review (and vote for/against) new answers within their expertise. A different, more productive sort of cleanup, if you will.

Comment: Following up on this topic, should the original q & a's regarding cleanup week be closed to avoid further confusion or do you feel that they have some historical value?

Comment: It would seem we should [close them or re-tag them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204200/how-do-we-now-close-meta-questions-that-are-no-longer-relevant?noredirect=1&lq=1)